# How to access objects of app Delegate into RootViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a navigation based app in which i am calling a web service. I have done all the work which is required in the background to absorb the web services. The only thing left is to display it in a Table view. 
The data i want to display is stored in a Mutable array and i can see the data in console and this is in app delegate. I just want to pass this data somehow to root so that i can display it in table view.
Could somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.yourArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

The smarter thing to do is to create an instance of an NSMutableArray in your root view, then have that feed off of the appDelegate array.

Comment: i have a mutable array in app delegate named 'a' and i want this to be available in my rootviewcontroller to display it in table view. How should i do that

Answer (score 5):

In appDelegate .h file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *array;
```

in AppDelegate.m file

```
@synthesis array;
```

In rootViewController file

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 NSLog(@"array is %@",appDelegate.array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would likely change your design approach and create a controller that fetches and persists the data.  Your are coupling your `AppDelegate` to your controller and making it responsible for the data retrieval.  This doesn't necessarily fit the MVC approach that is baked into iOS.

By creating a a data object class that is responsible for data retrieval (eg, calling/caching the web service data), you make your code more reusable and easier to use by the parts of your program.

Answer (score 0):

In Appdelgate.h create your string

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *deviceToken;
+ (AppDelegate *)getAppDelegate;
```

Appdelegate.m implement

```
+ (AppDelegate *)getAppDelegate{
  static AppDelegate* mAppDelegate = nil;
  if(!mAppDelegate)
  {
     UIApplication *lApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
     if([lApplication.delegate isKindOfClass: [AppDelegate class]])
     {
         mAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)lApplication.delegate;
     }
   }
 return mAppDelegate;
}
```

and access this string into where you need, create variable for appdelegate

```
AppDelegate *mLoginAppDelegate;
```

in viewdidload write these lines

```
if(!mLoginAppDelegate)
    mLoginAppDelegate = [AppDelegate getAppDelegate];

NSLog(@"Device Token: %@", mLoginAppDelegate.deviceToken);
```